# Java 1.6 abstracted random access

Tags: java, abstraction, random-access

As a java guru, what would you suggest to abstract random access so that a code can be agnostic to whether the data its accessing is in memory or in a file on the harddrive?

(The files in question could be several gigabytes in size. Having random access is the most important feature.)

Comment: I posted a comment here, but then I realized that I may have misinterpreted "to abstract", so I removed it. To ensure, your actual question is which Java 1.6 (N)IO API to choose for random access?

Comment: Yes, that's a better way to ask the question than I did. What would the Java API solution to abstracted random access from a Byte[] or File?

Comment: OK, you already have the right answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [Java NIO](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/) is for.

See [Random Access Files](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html) and [Memory-mapped files](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_029.htm).

Comment: This looks like a good solution for my application. Thank you very much Stack Overflow, and cletus and BalusC and bmargulies and danben!

Answer (score 1):

I can offer memory mapping of files. Those give you a java.nio.ByteBuffer. And you can also make those as ordinary in-memory objects, so there you go, perfect agnosis, if not perfect ignorance.

And we've had them since [1.4](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html).

The question is in some respects unclear. If you want file-style access, you are rather out of luck, since a RandomAccessFile can't be constructed over any in-memory resource.